# Why absolute-value function is not a continuous function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing a pre-calculus course from:  https://www.edx.org/course/pre-university-calculus

It tells me that a continuous function has continuous graphs while a piece-wise function has kind of step-based graph. Then it tells that absolute value function |x| is a piece-wise function. I noticed the |x| has a continuous graph without any breaks.  How come it  is defined piece-wise then ?

Wikipedia says it is both continuous and piece-wise linear function. I am confused:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Absolute_value_function

Comment: The absolute value function is indeed continuous. Not all piecewise-defined functions are discontinuous.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing "piecewise" with "step". The absolute value function has a piecewise definition, but as you and the text correctly observe, it is continuous. Informally, the pieces touch at the transition points.

The greatest integer function has a piecewise definition and is a step function. There are breaks in its graph at the integers.

I think you should read the text carefully to see whether it is as confused as you are. If so, then it should be corrected.

Comment: You mean, there are 2 things:  "piecewise definition"  (PD) and then "piecewise function" (PF).  PF means graph without breaks while PD means function defined with more than one equation. Did I get it correctly ?

Comment: "piecewise" means "defined in pieces", often with a different equation for each piece. A piecewise function is a function with a piecewise definition. That's just one concept. Continuity is another. Some piecewise defined functions are continuous, some not.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan,  this one clears it up :) . They are 2 different concepts .

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have a piecewise function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}g(x) & x\leq a \\ h(x) & x>a\end{matrix}\right.$$
$f(x)$ is continuous if $g(x)$ is continuous when $x\leq a$, $h(x)$ is continuous when $x>a$, and $g(a)=h(a)$ (which is indeed the case for the absolute value function).